# Ubuntu and proxy

Tags: networking, updates, proxy

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I can't get updates using `sudo apt-get`. I tried setting up a proxy using GUI settings and using this command in the terminal:

```
export http_proxy="http://user:password@host:port
```

Yet nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: you should give additional information on how your network is set up. have you looked at your proxy's logs to see if there are connection attempts? What does tcpdump show? What is the actual error message? "Does not work" is not adequate information!

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file on "/etc/apt/apt.conf" 

Edit "apt.conf" file and add the below lines  

Acquire::http::proxy "http://admin:proxyusername@192.168.0.1:3128/"; 

Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://admin:proxyusername@192.168.0.1:3128/"; 

Acquire::https::proxy "https://admin:proxyusername@192.168.0.1:3128/";

Once all done restart squid or squid3 services. and try to update

Comment: Okey, I'll try that once i finish configuration my freeNAS :)

Comment: What do you mean by "admin" in the proxy format, i do have my username and password to access the internet but i am not sure what i should replace "admin" with.

Comment: Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@192.168.0.1:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@192.168.0.1:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@192.168.0.1:3128/";